# hazelcast: connection strategy: ON vs ASYNC

Tags: hazelcast

https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.2/troubleshoot/recovery-clients

What will be the difference b/w ClientConnectionStrategyConfig.ReconnectMode.ON and ASYNC?

Does ON means client keep retrying for a connection, until any of the members is up?

What about ASYNC?

Answer (score 1):

As described [here](https://docs.hazelcast.com/hazelcast/5.3/clients/java#java-client-connection-strategy), the client will try to reconnect both in the ON and ASYNC modes. The difference comes from the fate of the pending invocations during that time. With the ON mode, the requests are blocked i.e. you don't get a result back for your API calls until the client reconnects. With the ASYNC mode, requests are failed immediately with the HazelcastClientOfflineException.

Comment: can you describe more on 'pending invocations'? what is the diff b/w OFF and ASYNC?

Comment: I meant the API calls you made, like map.get. So, if you make a map.get call while the client is disconnected or trying to reconnect, with ON mode the call will block (won't return a response) and with the ASYNC mode, you will get HazelcastClientOfflineException immediately.